# gpg: can't connect to the agent: Invalid value passed to IPC

Tags: git-bash, gnupg, maven-gpg-plugin

**Dev environment:** Mingw64 that came with Git Bash.

I am trying to sign with `maven-gpg-plugin`:

```
 [INFO] --- maven-gpg-plugin:1.6:sign (sign-release-artifacts) @ systemds ---
[INFO] gpg: keybox 'F:\Repo\systemds/pubring.kbx' created
[INFO] gpg: can't connect to the agent: Invalid value passed to IPC
[INFO] gpg: no default secret key: No secret key
[INFO] gpg: signing failed: No secret key
```

After setting `GNUPGHOME`,
the error message:

```
[INFO] [INFO] --- maven-gpg-plugin:1.6:sign (sign-release-artifacts) @ systemds ---
[INFO] gpg: can't connect to the agent: Invalid value passed to IPC
[INFO] gpg: can't connect to the agent: Invalid value passed to IPC
[INFO] gpg: keydb_search failed: No agent running
[INFO] gpg: no default secret key: No agent running
[INFO] gpg: signing failed: No agent running
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting the environmental variable for `GNUPGHOME` resolves the issue.

```sh
export GNUPGHOME=$HOME/.gnupg
```

Note: Do not use `~` as `~/.gnupg` for representing home.

---

**Explanation:**

The plugin tried to create the key files  in the current directory as we can see by the line

```
[INFO] gpg: keybox 'F:\Repo\systemds/pubring.kbx' created
```

which is resolved after pointing out the `GNUPGHOME`.